# self copying file to new location tchar incompatible to char

Tags: c++

I am trying to set the destination folder , along with the desntination file path to copy itself to the new location , but however I am using `strcpy , and strcat`

> argument of type "TCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type
>   "char *"

how can I keep the same code structure , and behavior to self copy the file to the new location?

```c
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR szFilepath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szFilename[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szDestpath[MAX_PATH];

    /* Get the current executable's full path */
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilepath, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << "filepath: " << szFilepath << std::endl;

    /* Extract just the name */
    GetFileTitle(szFilepath, szFilename, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << "filename: " << szFilename << std::endl;

    //Set the destination folder path
    strcpy(szDestpath, "D:\\");

    //Set the destination file path
    strcat(szDestpath, szFilename);

    std::wcout << "dest path: " << szDestpath << std::endl;

    // copys the file of your '.exe'

    if (!CopyFile(szFilepath, szDestpath, FALSE)) {
        std::cout << "couldnt copy the file";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "good";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `TCHAR`, so replace `strcpy()` with `_tcscpy()`, and `strcat()` with `_tcscat()`.

Comment: sure it does , but without .exe how can I integrate it without breaking the code?

Comment: Change your project char set to multibyte

Comment: Probably already is multibyte. @victor_angel27 if you're going to live in a `TCHAR` world, you'll have to use pretty much nothing `TCHAR` support functions. If you use anything else, you're inviting problems.

Comment: @user4581301 "*Probably already is multibyte*" - actually, the project would have to be set to Unicode in order to get this error, because `TCHAR` would be `wchar_t` being passed to `strcpy()`/`strcat()` expecting `char*`.  Had the project been set to ANSI/Multibyte instead, `TCHAR` would be `char` and there would be no error.